# Cannot replace object value in if statement

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am making a tutorial for a forums and actually got stuck while making it ! How can I apply the string 'Uber' to groupIs in my first if statement if true ? This doesn't work. Thanks :)

```
var User = function(username, groupIs, warnings, postCount) {
    this.username = username;
    this.groupIs = groupIs;
    this.warnings = warnings;
    this.postCount = postCount;
}

var worker = new User('Worker', 'Uber', 0, 1500);
var normalMember = new User('ImAnormalMember', 'normal', 0, 2000);
var l33tMember = new User('l33tboy', 'L33t', 0, 800);
var $3picmemberRIP = new User('epicMember', '3pic', 20, 800);



function upgradeChecker(member, group, warning, posts) {

    if ((group != 'Uber' && posts > 1000) && warning === 0) {

       console.log(member + ' Congrats on Uber !');
       group = "Uber";
    } else if (posts < 1000 && warning === 0) {
        console.log(member + ' You have ' + posts + ' posts, you do not meet the requirements');

    } else if (warning != 0 && posts > 1000) {
        console.log(member + ' You cannot upgrade with ' + warning + ' warning')
    } else if (posts < 1000 && warning != 0) {
        console.log(member + ' you have ' + posts + ' posts which is less than 1000 and you have ' + warning + '% warning. You cannot upgrade');
    } else {
        console.log(member + ' You are already Uber');
    }

}

upgradeChecker(worker.username, worker.groupIs, worker.warnings, worker.postCount);
upgradeChecker(normalMember.username, normalMember.groupIs, normalMember.warnings, normalMember.postCount);
upgradeChecker(l33tMember.username, l33tMember.groupIs, l33tMember.warnings, l33tMember.postCount);
upgradeChecker($3picmemberRIP.username, $3picmemberRIP.groupIs, $3picmemberRIP.warnings, $3picmemberRIP.postCount);
```

Comment: Don't use the properties of the `User`, instead pass the `User` object to `upgradeChecker`. You can then modify the properties of the `User`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mind showing me with a code snippet ?

Comment: @szeb where do you see spaces ?

Comment: We do here in europe...

Comment: @szeb I am french :)

Comment: @Andreas mind showing an example please?

Comment: `function upgradeChecker(userToCheck) { if (userToCheck.member === ...) { ... } /* ... */ }` -> `upgradeChecker(worker); upgradeChecker(normalMember);`

Answer (score 1):

Right now the upgradeChecker is a function that receives numbers and strings and it changes those values. It doesn't recognize those values as properties of an object. What you can do instead is modify that function so it receives a complete object and it will then modify its properties.

```js
var User = function(username, groupIs, warnings, postCount) {
  this.username = username;
  this.groupIs = groupIs;
  this.warnings = warnings;
  this.postCount = postCount;
}

var worker = new User('Worker', 'Uber', 0, 1500);
var normalMember = new User('ImAnormalMember', 'normal', 0, 2000);
var l33tMember = new User('l33tboy', 'L33t', 0, 800);
var $3picmemberRIP = new User('epicMember', '3pic', 20, 800);


function upgradeChecker(user) {
  if ((user.groupIs != 'Uber' && user.postCount > 1000) && user.warnings === 0) {
    console.log(user.username + ' Congrats on Uber !');
    user.groupIs = "Uber";
  } else if (user.postCount < 1000 && user.warnings === 0) {
    console.log(user.username + ' You have ' + user.postCount + ' posts, you do not meet the requirements');
  } else if (user.warnings != 0 && user.postCount > 1000) {
    console.log(user.username + ' You cannot upgrade with ' + user.warnings + ' warning')
  } else if (user.postCount < 1000 && user.warnings != 0) {
    console.log(user.username + ' you have ' + user.postCount + ' posts which is less than 1000 and you have ' + user.warnings + '% warning. You cannot upgrade');
  } else {
    console.log(user.username + ' You are already Uber');
  }
}

upgradeChecker(worker);
upgradeChecker(l33tMember);
upgradeChecker($3picmemberRIP);

upgradeChecker(normalMember);
console.log(normalMember.groupIs);
```

Comment: That is exactly it, so upgradeChecker didn't have access to the properties. So if the User object is passed into the function argument then there is a reference point. Thanks a lot, it will really help me :)